# дверями vs дверьми

Tags: выбор-слова, падежи, окончания

What's the difference between *дверями* and *дверьми*? My textbook states that «дверьми» is bookish, however upon searching more into this I found some articles claiming that they are **completely** interchangeable. So does it matter which one I choose?

Comment: if you wish to speak good Russian, **дверьми** is the right choice in my opinion

Comment: An article from a popular science magazine **Наука и жизнь**: https://www.nkj.ru/archive/articles/21442/ The version **дверьми** is called to be 'closer to colloquial'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Despite they are completely interchangeable, the latter is a bit bookish.

Ending `-ьми` in instrumental case plural is lost, except for these words:

- `дочери` - `дочерьми` / `дочерями`,
- `лошади` - `лошадьми` / `лошадями`,
- `двери` - `дверьми` / `дверями`,
- `плети` - `плетьми` / `плетями` (thanks @user31264),
- `звери` - `зверями` (preferable) / `зверьми` (obsolete),
- `дети` - `детьми` only,
- `люди` - `людьми` only (thanks @БаянКупи-ка),
- `кости` - `костями`, except the phrase `лечь костьми`.

Comment: Also *бить (хлестать, наказывать, сечь и т.д.) плетьми*

Comment: In fact, when плеть is a flogging device, or when it is compared to lifeless hands/legs, *плетьми* is used in almost all cases.  When плеть is part of a plant or similar inanimate object,  *плетями* is used.

Comment: @user31264 Thank you. Added to the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Stats from the [Russian National Corpus](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?sort=gr_tagging&out=normal&dpp=100&spd=10&seed=2891&env=alpha&mydocsize=107321&text=lexgramm&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%E4%E2%E5%F0%FC&gramm1=pl%2Cins&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=&mode=main&mycorp=(((sphere%253A%2522%25ED%25E5%25F5%25F3%25E4%25EE%25E6%25E5%25F1%25F2%25E2%25E5%25ED%25ED%25E0%25FF%2522)))&mysent=&mysize=160351999&mysentsize=11540232):

- Literary texts (Художественные тексты):
  дверями: 52%, дверьми: 48%
- Non-literary texts (Нехудожественные тексты):
  дверями: 74%, дверьми: 26%

(Based on the first 100 documents.)

This confirms that **дверьми** is more bookish (48% vs 26%) and that in literary texts the two are interchangeable (52% vs 48%). In other genres (news, speech) **дверями** prevails (74% vs 26%).